# Iterate over json file in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having hard time in success to iterate over my external json file in Vue.

I'm importing the file like this:

```
import json from '../../public/platform.json'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        
            currentPage: 0,
            brand: '',
            platform: '',
            affiliate: '',
            myJson: json,
    }),
```

Json file looking like this:

```
{
            "Example": {
                "Username": "",
                "Password": "",
                "AffiliateID": "",
                "GI": "",
                "CI": "",
                "freeTextArea": ""
            },
            "ExampleTwo": {
                "Username": "",
                "Password": "",
                "freeTextArea": ""
            }
}
```

My goal is to do as follows:
I want to check if the "platform" from data is matching "Example" or "ExampleTwo" and if it does, I want to access the fields within either of them.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `computed` property as follows:

```
computed: {
  myPlatform: function () { return json[this.platform] || {}; },
}
```

Here is a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-gould-3hkbl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: How can i get each value seperated?

Comment: You can use ``Object#entries`` if you want the ``key-value`` pairs, or ``Object#values`` if you only want the values of the resulting object

Comment: Can  I have an example?